# Matrix norm can assume infinite values?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given a real-valued matrix $A=a_{i,j} \in M_{n,n}$

When: $||A||_2= \sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^n a^2_{i,j}} < + \infty$ ? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking why it is finite, it is a finite sum of finite elements and therefore finite.

Comment: Thank you. 
And If I have $t \rightarrow A(t)$ continuous in $(a,b)\subset R$ , 

$|| A(t)||_2$ is still finite?

Comment: For $t \in (a,b)$ yes I believe so.  Note that this doesn't apply to limits.  

Consider, for example the interval $(0,1)$ and the map
$$t \to \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{t} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then for any $t \in (0,1)$ the norm is finite, however, if we take the norm under $t \to 0$, this goes to infinity.

Comment: In a compact subset of $J \subset (a,b)$ it should be true, cause $||A(t)||_2 \le max_{t \in J} ||A(t)||_2$

Comment: Yes that is correct.